# How do I configure absolute paths for imports in TypeScript based React Native apps?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, jestjs, babeljs

In order to avoid '../../../../' style relative imports in a TypeScript based React Native app, I would like to configure the app so that I can use absolute imports instead.

It is important that the configuration also supports Jest unit tests.

I created the app using `npx react-native init MyTestApp --template typescript`

React Native version: 0.60.5

What is the exact configuration I would need to achieve this?

Comment: `I've added in the root of my project. the usual `tsconfig.json` however if your using Create React App you may want to add an additional file for the paths callled `tsconfig.base.json` and extend it in you're initial main tsconfig it will loolk like this


``` json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

### Requirement

```
// Meh
import config from '../../../../../../../config';

// Awesome!
import config from '@cuteapp/config';
```

### How To

1. Add this babel plugin package

```
yarn add --dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

2. My `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      require.resolve('babel-plugin-module-resolver'),
      {
        cwd: 'babelrc',
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.ios.js', '.android.js'],
        alias: {
          '@cuteapp': './app'
        }
      }
    ],
    'jest-hoist'
  ]
};
```

3. My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2015.promise", "es2016.array.include", "dom"],
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@cuteapp/*": ["app/*/index", "app/*"]
    },
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "types": ["jest"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js"]
}
```

4. Restart the IDE.
5. That's it.

Comment: One tiny (yet potentially confusing) thing - it's `babel-config-js` (not `json`)

Comment: also the `tsconfig.json` `jsx` key should be `react-native` per the question.

Comment: Make sure to run `yarn start —reset-cache` after setting this :-)

Comment: working with this approach. thnx @i-putu-yoga-permana
I'm using RN 0.71 on Windows 11

Answer (score 40):

Summary:

The npm package `babel-plugin-module-resolver` is needed, as well as some configuration in `tsconfig.json` and `babel.config.js`

---

Step by step:

1. Install `babel-plugin-module-resolver` using npm or yarn.

   ```sh
   npm i babel-plugin-module-resolver --save-dev

   # Or (If you're using yarn):

   yarn add --dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
   ```
2. `tsconfig.json`: Add `"baseUrl": "."` to `compilerOptions`
3. `babel.config.js`: Add a key named `plugins` with the following value:

```
[
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        extensions: [
          '.js',
          '.jsx',
          '.ts',
          '.tsx',
          '.android.js',
          '.android.tsx',
          '.ios.js',
          '.ios.tsx'
        ],
        root: ['.']
      }
    ]
  ]
```

---

Complete configuration:

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"]
}
```

`babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        extensions: [
          '.js',
          '.jsx',
          '.ts',
          '.tsx',
          '.android.js',
          '.android.tsx',
          '.ios.js',
          '.ios.tsx'
        ],
        root: ['.']
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

This is for a clean new project created using `npx react-native init MyTestApp --template typescript` on React Native version 0.60.5

Comment: babel-plugin-module-resolver should be installed to devDependencies

Comment: Yep, this works. Something to note here is that there is a much simpler way https://egghead.io/lessons/react-native-reduce-long-import-statements-in-react-native-with-absolute-imports

Answer (score 14):

If you do not want to use the babel plugin

1. create a new `package.json` file inside the `src` folder with the following. (change `myapp` to whatever you want to, it can even be `src`.)

```
{
  "name": "myapp"
}
```

2. update your tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     ...
     "baseUrl": "./",
     "paths": {
       "myapp/*": ["src/*"]
     }
     ...
  }
}
```

3. In your.tsx file

```
import { MyThing } from 'myapp/MyThing';
```

Comment: This is the best solution in my opinion. The only downside is you have a package.json at each level you need it.

Comment: It does not immediately appear that you even need the compilerOptions, although I haven't yet compiled my app for a Production release. I'm not sure yet if it is "getting compiled" in my current Debug release.

Comment: Best solution without installing an extra dependency on node modules hole.

Comment: How to put more than one `name` in the `package.json` please?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on this @Tomus?  If your looking to have multiple paths, then you need a separate `package.json` file in each folder with a single `name` property.

Comment: I would like to declare 2 aliases, which will be accessible in all folders/files of `src`, I don't know if I was clear, sorry ^^

Comment: @Tomus I don't think this could be achieved this way, the `package.json` file only has a single string property for `name`.  Perhaps you could create an empty folder within that `package.json` files folder location with another `package.json` file in there with the second alias name, then add a new path with that alias like `"myapp2/../*": ["src/*"]` mind you this is all theory at this point and would need some testing to see if that would work.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 9):

**2023 Update**

1.Create a `package.json` in your `src` folder.And add `{"name":"src"}` in it.

2.Update your `tsconfig.json` file like this,

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     ...
     "baseUrl": "./",
     "paths": {
       "src/*": ["src/*"]
     }
     ...
  }
}
```

3.Restart your ide.

Now you can import like this,

```
import MyComponent from 'src/components/MyComponent';
```

Comment: That's working also in 2023 with `"react-native": "^0.71.7"`

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who uses TypeScript and just wants to use import with absolute paths **without** aliases.

Assuming all of your code folders are inside of `src`.

Insert `"baseUrl": "src"` in `compilerOptions` object inside `tsconfig.json`.

Now you can use absolute paths in imports.

Comment: This will only get the type checking working, will not help in the compile

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do if you have a "src" file on your project root is to add a package.json file in it and write `{ "name": "src" }` in it. Then every import named "src/..." resolves beautifully.

I found this solution in [this video](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-native-reduce-long-import-statements-in-react-native-with-absolute-imports).

Answer (score 3):

All of the other answers didn't work for me with a freshly created React Native + Typescript project.

What worked for me was setting both `baseUrl` and `paths` in `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "NAME_IN_PACKAGE_JSON/*": ["./*"]
    }
}
```

Replace NAME_IN_PACKAGE_JSON with your `package.json`'s name field.
E.g. if the name field is `myapp` you can do:

`import HomeScreen from "myapp/screens/HomeScreen";`

Comment: When I try to set `"paths"`, I get this at build time: `The following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file:
  - compilerOptions.paths must not be set (aliased imports are not supported)`, but apparently just the `"baseUrl"` setting is enough now. At least for me, it works fine.

Answer (score -3):

You can solve it using  **5** simple steps **withou eject**:

**Step 1**: Adding react-app-rewired into your `devDependencies`.


`yarn add -D react-app-rewired` or `npm intall react-app-rewired --save-dev`

**Step 2**: After installation, you'll be able to change `package.json` default ReactsJS scripts to:

```
"scripts": {  
  "start": "react-app-rewired start",  
  "build": "react-app-rewired build",  
  "test": "react-app-rewired test",  
  "eject": "react-app-rewired eject" 
}
```

**Step 3**: Creates a new file called `tsconfig.paths.json` on root path, with content like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "services/*": ["./src/shared/services/*"],
      "interfaces/*": ["./src/shared/interfaces/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Tip 1**: you can choose which path you want to use, like:
`@services, @interface, @src, ~, @, etc` just by changing the keys inside `"paths": {}`

The same is applied to it's value: `["src/shared/services/"], ["src/shared/interfaces/"], ["src/*"]`, use the relative path here.

**Step 4**: Into `tsconfig.json`, before `"compilerOptions"` you need to extends the `tsconfig.paths.json` you just created.


Like this:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  ...//rest of file infos compilerOptions, include... whatever
}
```

**Step 5**: Creates a new file `config-overrides.js`, adding your alias and relative paths on it:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function override(config) {
  config.resolve = {
    ...config.resolve,
    alias: {
      ...config.alias,
      'services': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/shared/services'),
      'interfaces': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/shared/interfaces')
    },
  };

  return config;
};
```

**Tip 2**: If you're using `eslint`, remember to have an `.eslintignore` file and add `config-overrides.js` within it.


Restart your IDE or text editor, in my case VSCode.

It's **DONE!**. Now just run `yarn start` or `npm run start`