# tsconfig paths does not resolve in react native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, babeljs

I'm attempting to use TypeScript's [`paths`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) option in my `tsconfig.json` file. I've used paths before in my other *web* applications using React. Yet, for some reason, *Native* refuses to work with it.

This is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
// Added by default by React Native
"extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",
// My options
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./App",
    "paths": {
        "@Assets/*": ["Assets/*"],
        "@Image/*": ["Assets/Images/*"],
    },
    "skipLibCheck": true,
}
```

This is my folder structure:

```
project
|__App
|  |__Main.tsx
|  |__Assets
|     |__Images
|        |__Test.png
|__tsconfig.json
```

And inside my `Main.tsx` file, this is how I'm attempting to use it:

```
const test = require("@Image/Test.png");
```

But, this results in the error:

> Unable to resolve module *@Image/Test.png* from *project/App/Main.tsx*: *@Image/Test.png* could not be found within the project or in these directories.

I've attempted all of the answers within [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57798793/how-do-i-configure-absolute-paths-for-imports-in-typescript-based-react-native-a) with no different outcome.

I know that the file *does exist* because it works perfectly fine when I change the `require` path to the absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

After extensively searching for this issue, I came across this blog [1], where the author used a regex pattern instead of static path and it worked for me.

`babel.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        root: ["."],
        alias: {
          // "@/": "./src/"  ❌ not working
          "^@/(.+)": "./src/\\1", // ✅ works
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

`tsconfig.json`

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      //We will have to add the same thing in babel.config.js
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
    //other options
  }
  //other configs
}
```

Reference

1 - https://pratapsharma.com.np/path-alias-in-a-typescript-project