# absolute path does not work (base url in tsconfig

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, tsconfig

In the screenshot below you can see my folder structure on the left, metro error in terminal and my tsconfig.json with baseUrl: './src'. I have also attached a screenshot of my app.ts and MainTabs.ts for extra context.

Does anyone have any ideas for why my absolute path is displaying this error in my terminal?
[image: Example]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you mean `/navigation`?

Comment: @Konrad I am unsure honestly, but when I do try this solution I get - TS2307: Cannot find module '/navigation/tabs/MainTabs' or its corresponding type declarations.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the solution here: [How do I configure absolute paths for imports in TypeScript based React Native apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57798793/how-do-i-configure-absolute-paths-for-imports-in-typescript-based-react-native-a)

You either need to configure a babel plugin or put a package.json in your `src/` directory that looks like `{ name: 'src' }`. The name value in the package.json isn't important.

Comment: Hey, this looks like a valid solution. But, I am just wondering - shouldn't I be able to implement this without babel-plugin-module-resolver and the package.json solution. Shouldn't baseUrl in my tsconfig be enough?

Comment: Yes, yes you should. It's not supported out of the box though. Typescript is the engine that reads the code and makes sense of it in your IDE, but it doesn't replace paths with meaningful paths so we have to tell babel to do it or hack the module resolution system.

Comment: Can you show me how to configure it using baseUrl in the tsconfig with the code I have given? I am not looking to maintain another package and I am not a fan of the package.json solution

Comment: The answer I linked to has the code you need. You can't do it without the babel plugin or package.json. You're not maintaining another package, just adding a file to make the `baseUrl` work. Quickest and easiest approach, that's what I would do.